# Get embed footer from reaction message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want the person who used the command to be able to delete the result. I have put the user's ID in the footer of the embed, and my question is: how do I get that data from the message where the user reacted to.

`reaction.message.embed.footer` doesn't work. I currently don't have code as I was trying to get that ID first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord.Message` object has no attribute `embed`, but it has `embeds`. It returns you a list of embeds that the message has. So you can simply do: `reaction.message.embeds[0].footer`.

Comment: I am getting the result 3 times in `EmbedProxy(text='339367606949642242')`. Do you know how I can remove these other 2 and the EmbedProxy thing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't but I guess you can do `str(result)` then you can remove the unwanted parts.